# Getting textbox value inside a Detailsview control

Tags: asp.net, .net-3.5, detailsview, nested-controls

I have a DetailsView control with a template field as follows:

```
<asp:TemplateField SortExpression="Title">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtMessageTitle" Text='<%# Bind("Title") %>' runat="server">
    </asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button ID="btnUpdateTitle" runat="server" Text="Update" 
      CommandName="UpdateTitle" CommandArgument='<%# Bind("MessageID") %>' oncommand="btnUpdateCommand"/>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

The Details View is wrapped inside an UpdatePanel.

When the user clicks on `btnUpdateButton` I'd like to be able to retrieve the textbox (`txtMessageTitle`) value in code behind and by using CommandArgument of the button, update the appropriate MessageTitle in database. How can I retrieve the textbox value inside the DetailsView control from the Command event of my button?
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use the following:

```
   TextBox txtMessageTitle = detailsViewName.FindControl("txtMessageTitle") as TextBox;
   string text = txtMessageTitle.Text;
```